# Comparing ln(y) =bX vs. OLS and other count data models

Tags: poisson-distribution, stata, least-squares

My data is a balanced panel:
12 years $\cdot$ 600 ids $\cdot$ 12 months = 86,400 observations.

For about 150 of my 600 ids, at a certain point in this 12 year period a treatment is applied switching them to the "treated" or "on" state. A dummy variable AFTER indicates when this is true.

My outcome is a count, positive only and quite skewed, looks like a power law.

I'm interested in estimating the impact of treatment on outcome.

I've tried these 3 specifications in STATA and I dont seem to understand why they don't accord well with each other.

1. OLS $\rightarrow$ `reg y AFTER i.id i.year, robust cluster(id)`
2. Log $\rightarrow$ `reg ln(y) AFTER i.id i.year, robust cluster(id)`
3. Poisson $\rightarrow$ `xtpoisson y AFTER i.year, fe vce(robust)`
4. Negative Binomial $\rightarrow$ `nbreg y AFTER i.id i.year, vce(robust)`

Here i.id and i.year are fixed effects for id and year respectively.

Estimated coeffs with standard errors in parentheses are as follows:

1. OLS: `403922 (223946) *`
2. Log : `-0.664 (0.0252) ***`
3. Poisson : `-.0188 (0.019)`

Could someone interpret these for me and tell me why one model would give me a poistive coeff while other give me a negative one? My theory tells me it should be positive, but im not sure why this should be the case that the non linear models give me a different answer.

Sum stats for my outcome variable are:

range: `[0,3.025e+08]` 
unique values: `59,191` 
mean: `1.3e+06` 
std. dev: `1.1e+07`

percentiles: `10% (0), 25% (13480), 50% (74690), 75% (322982), 90% (1.3e+06)`

Comment: What happens when you try a non-panel version of poisson? Also, what happened to the negative binomial?

Comment: What do you do with $\ln(0)$ since the outcome range seems to include that?

Comment: Hi Dimitriy, for ln(y), is simply transform to ln(y+1) -- that deals with the ln(0)s. I will get back to you on the other question about the poisson.